# Missing Http header response parameter cache control and pragma in API response

Tags: api, rest, api-gateway, ibm-datapower

I am testing multiple API's and noticed one API missing response header parameters cache control and pragma in API response.
Want to check cache control and pragma parameters mandatory in API response ?
Is there any specific scope these header parameter missing in API response?

Please advice

Answer (score 1):

depends on the service object that you are using. In case of MPGW you need a custom filter or xform that validates the presence of the required headers. If you are using API Gateway object you can validate the response according to the API spec assuming that the headers you mentioned are defined as required in the spec.

--HP

Comment: We are IBM datapower/API gateway . want to check these header parameters configured at server level ?